# recv_into a numpy array

Tags: python, sockets, numpy

I am transmiting images by sockets from a camera that runs wince :(
The images in the camera are just float arrays created using realloc for the given x * y size

On the other end, I am receiving these images in python.
I have this code working doing

```
img_dtype = np.float32
img_rcv = np.empty((img_y, img_x), 
                   dtype = img_dtype)

p = sck.recv_into(img_rcv, 
                  int(size_bytes), 
                  socket.MSG_WAITALL)

if size_bytes != p:
    print "Mismatch between expected and received data amount"


 return img_rcv
```

I am a little bit confused about the way numpy creates its arrays and I am wondering if this img_rcv will be compatible with the way recv_into works.

My questions are:

- How safe is this?
- Does the memory allocation for the numpy array will be known for recv_into?
- Are the numpy arrays creation routines equivalent to a malloc?
- It is just working because I am lucky?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers are:

- safe
- yes, via the [buffer interface](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/buffer.html)
- yes, in the sense that you get a block of memory you can work with
- no